# grpc web channel setup for authenticated request in Blazer with dotnet 8 authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, grpc-web

I'm trying to upgrade a blazor 7 Wasm project to use dotnet 8 and the new authentication mechanism and I've hit a problem with creating the gRpc channel.

In dotnet 7 with microsoft.identity this was the channel setup (which worked):

```
var baseAddressMessageHandler = 
sp.GetRequiredService<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
baseAddressMessageHandler.InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
var grpcWebHandler = new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb, baseAddressMessageHandler);
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress, new 
GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = grpcWebHandler });
```

However - contrary to what the documetnation suggests - `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler` is not registered by the framework and there is no `IAccessTokenProvider` available for me to register it myself.

I've tried all the bits that I could think of from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-8.0

But I haven't managed to work out how to authenticate with gRpc yet. I'm not sure if I'm missing something or if I'm trying to do something that can't be done, but any help appreciated!

Comment: hi, this might help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-8.0#bearer-token-with-grpc-client-factory

Comment: Not quite - the interesting section is: // App code to resolve the token here. I'm trying to figure out how to get that using the new 8 identity but still coming up short. Annoyingly I think that MS have shot themselves in the foot here